# Compact Java syntax for conditional arguments?

Tags: java, syntax

What is the best (most compact) way to hand this situation:
One or more arguments to a method call depends on some condition, while the rest of the arguments are identical?

For example-- you want to

```
DeathRay mynewWpn = new DeathRay(particle.proton, chassisColor.BLACK, oem.ACME)
```

if

```
enemy_composition == nature.ANTIMATTER
```

but

```
DeathRay mynewWpn = new DeathRay(particle.anti-proton, chassisColor.BLACK, oem.ACME)
```

if

```
enemy_composition == nature.MATTER
```

Obviously you can `if-else` but it looks unnecessarily long when there are a lot of arguments or more than one conditional argument.  I have also done this creating an argument with an `if-else` beforehand and then calling the method.  Again, that seems kind of clunky.  Is there some sort of inline syntax similar to an Excel if-statement?

Comment: What is 'Excel if-statement'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
new DeathRay(enemy_composition == nature.ANTIMATTER ? particle.proton : particle.anti-proton, chassisColor.BLACK, oem.ACME)
```

… but I think we can all agree that's hideous. It also assumes that there are only two kinds of particle.

Here are some better alternatives.

`switch`:

```
particle type;
switch (enemy_composition) { /* Assuming "nature" is an enum. */
  case ANTIMATTER : 
    type = particle.proton;
    break;
  case MATTER : 
    type = particle.antiproton;
    break;
}
DeathRay mynewWpn = new DeathRay(type, chassisColor.BLACK, oem.ACME);
```

`enum` method:

Add a method to your `enum`, `Nature`.

```
public enum Nature
{

  MATTER
  {
    public Particle getCounterWeapon()
    {
      return Particle.ANTIPROTON;
    }
  },
  ANTIMATTER
  {
    public Particle getCounterWeapon()
    {
      return Particle.PROTON;
    }
  };

  public abstract Particle getCounterWeapon();

}
```

Then use it.

```
DeathRay mynewWpn = new DeathRay(enemy_composition.getCounterWeapon(), chassisColor.BLACK, oem.ACME);
```

`Map`:

```
particle type = counterWeapons.get(enemy_composition);
DeathRay mynewWpn = new DeathRay(type, chassisColor.BLACK, oem.ACME);
```

Comment: Might be easier to just pass parameter into enum constructor instead of defining same method 3 times. But goog answer anyway, +1

Comment: Yes, in this case it would be. Just wanted to show how to write totally different method for each enum instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's called the ternary operator `?:`

```
DeathRay mynewWpn = new DeathRay(
    enemy_composition == nature.ANTIMATTER ? particle.proton : particle.anti_proton,
    chassisColor.BLACK, oem.ACME);
```

The syntax is `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`, and it has the lowest operator precedence, although parentheses are often added to avoid confusion.

Comment: I find that parentheses are often added to show confusion, rather than avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

If `enemy_composition` can only be `nature.MATTER` or `nature.ANTIMATTER` then you could use a [ternery operator](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/oper/ternary.html):

```
DeathRay mynewWpn = new DeathRay(enemy_composition == nature.MATTER ? particle.anti-proton : particle.proton, chassisColor.BLACK, oem.ACME)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about redesigning some class?

In Nature class, compose some method like getDestroyer().

```
abstract class Enemy{
   abstract Weapon getDestroyer();
}
```

Then in concrete class like :

```
class MatterEnemy extends Enemy{
   Weapon getDestroyer(){return new DeathRay(antiproton, blabla);}
}
```

You implement such method. So your main class will be :

```
public static void main(String... args){
  Enemy enemy = new MatterEnemy();
  Weapon weapon = enemy.getDestroyer();
}
```

This way you can avoid conditional 'ifs'. Instead, the Enemy itself 'tells' you what weapon should be used to destroy them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MAP <strike>and the command pattern</strike> to avoid the `if-else`.

For eexample

```
Map<EnemyCompositionEnum,DeathRay> weapons = new HashMap<EnemyCompositionEnum,DeathRay>();

weapons.put(EnemyCompositionEnum.ANTIMATTER, new DeathRay(particle.proton,BLACK,oem.ACME));
weapons.put(EnemyCompositionEnum.MATTER, new DeathRay(particle.anti-proton,BLACK,oem.ACME));
```

And then use it

```
DeathRay weapon = weapons.get(enemy.composition);
```

## update

Ok , I just realized whats an Excel ternary operator by reading other answers.

Comment: I love it, and although it might be overkill compared to a ?: for this simple case, I can see many situations where this would come in handy.  I had no idea you could put things like that in the value fields of a map.  thanks

Comment: @Pete careful, ?: is the "Elvis" operator, that is available in Groovy and Spring EL. You are probably talking about the ternary operator a ? b : c. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators

Comment: In a Java context, ?: is a perfectly reasonable way of referring to the ternary operator.